# The database tab is appearing empty although it contains objects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The DataBase Tab is always empty

[image]

The database tab is appearing as following, the rules are opening fine and so does the other services like authentication and storage.
The tab is showing the expected JSON tree structure when my colleagues open it but it's not showing anything with me and I can't figure out why.

Comment: How do you know that it contains data? Are seeing data in code? If so, please edit your question by adding that code that reads your data.

Comment: If your colleague can see it. Then I would assume that it has something to do with your local machine/browser. The first few things you should try is to use incognito window, clear browser cache or check some firewall/antivirus which might be blocking firebase connections.

Comment: @goblin Thanks a lot the problem was solved when I switched browsers.